# Android Gesture Recognition bad

Tags: android, gesture

I've developed an app with gestures in Android.
It simply have four different gestures. Up, down, left and right.
Left and right works well, but up and down is never recognized. It also directly gets uncertain (I set the color to red so I can debug a faster way).

Here's my controller code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.gesture.Gesture;
import android.gesture.GestureLibraries;
import android.gesture.GestureLibrary;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener;
import android.gesture.Prediction;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class PreperationActivity extends Activity implements OnGesturePerformedListener {

    private GestureLibrary gestureLib;
    private ImageView ivProfileImage;
    private TextView list1, list2, list3, list4;
    private TextView tvUsername;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        GestureOverlayView gestureOverlayView = new GestureOverlayView(this);
        View inflate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_preperation, null);
        gestureOverlayView.addView(inflate);
//      gestureOverlayView.setGestureVisible(false);
        gestureOverlayView.setGestureColor(Color.BLACK);
        gestureOverlayView.setUncertainGestureColor(Color.RED);
        gestureOverlayView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
        gestureLib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
        if (!gestureLib.load()) {
            finish();
        }

        setContentView(gestureOverlayView);
        ivProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivProfileImage);
        ivProfileImage.setImageBitmap(ListActivity.friends.peek().profileImage);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        list1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        list2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
        list3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list3);
        list4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list4);

        list1.setText(intent.getStringExtra("list1"));
        list2.setText(intent.getStringExtra("list2"));
        list3.setText(intent.getStringExtra("list3"));
        list4.setText(intent.getStringExtra("list4"));

        tvUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUsername);
        tvUsername.setText(ListActivity.friends.peek().username);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.preperation, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {

        ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gestureLib.recognize(gesture);

        for (Prediction prediction : predictions) {
            Log.i("ced", "PREDICTION: " + prediction.score);
            if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
                Friend friend =ListActivity.friends.pop();
                ivProfileImage.setImageBitmap(friend.profileImage);
                tvUsername.setText(friend.username);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my view:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
tools:context=".PreperationActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@color/list_area_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@color/list_area_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/list_area_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@color/list_area_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivProfileImage"
    android:layout_width="183dp"
    android:layout_height="183dp"
    android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_square" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvUsername"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="5pt"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: My gestures from the Gesture Builder]

R is just to see if it works and yes, it does.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have u called this method : `addOnGesturePerformedListener` ?

I runned the legacy demo then I found that `OnGesturePerformedListener` causes single up&down gesture not be recognized.